# Google reCaptcha 3 - Error with login after first failed

Tags: php, recaptcha

I implement google reCaptcha 3 in my side. for some reason if the user type wrong details, and got an error of course, he cant try to login again. he gots reCaptcha message - "recaptcha_error(2)".

BTW - If he types correctly, in the first time, he does manage to connect.

Why is that and how i can fix that?

my form and script part

```
<form id="login-form" action="#" >

    <input type="hidden" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="validate_captcha">                        

    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">

    <button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=MY_SITE_KEY"></script>
<script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    // do request for recaptcha token
    // response is promise with passed token
        grecaptcha.execute('MY_SITE_KEY', {action:'validate_captcha'})
                  .then(function(token) {
            // add token value to form
            document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = token;
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is my PHP part

```
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
} else {
    $captcha = false;
}

if (!$captcha) {

     $msg = 'recaptcha_error(1)';
     
} else {
    $secret   = 'MY_SERVER_KEY';
    $response = file_get_contents(
        "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $secret . "&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    );

    $response = json_decode($response);

    
    if ($response->success === false) {

        $msg = 'recaptcha_error(2)';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first add `method="post"` to <form tag because by default form uses method GET and in PHP you were looking for POST data